# How to add Watermark in Reportviewer 2010?

Tags: reportviewer, report-viewer2010

Currently I build vb.net application and I use report viewer, but I want to add watermark (text) at the background of my report. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may basically add a text box from tool box, make the color gray, increase the font size and paste all other elements over this text box.